# Is the method name "is" of "RequestVar" a short name of some other words?

Tags: scala, lift

In lift web framework, the `RequestVar` has a method `is`:

```
def is: T

The current value of the variable
```

I wonder why the method name is `is`? Is it a short name of some other words? If it is the word `is`, I would expect it to return some boolean values, but it will return the value it holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say `is` is supposed to answer the question "What **is** the current value of the variable?".

It does not make sense to test for existence, as `RequestVars` (and `SessionsVars` for that matter) *are* always. If it confuses you, just use `get` ;)